# Can't pull code from azure devops (asking for password)

Tags: git, azure-devops, ssh-keys

I accidently borked my old wsl instance. So I setup a new wsl instance and generated an new ssh key. I uploaded the ssh key to azure devops. Now when i try to pull code from original source folder location its asking me for a password. Strangely I can pull code without any issues if i switch to a new location but i would like to use the original location. Does anyone know what could be going on?

Comment: Is there any hard-coded authentication config in the `.git/config` of your original location? Or a path-conditioned config in your `~/.gitconfig`?

Comment: @zigarn thanks a bunch. That helped me figure out the issue. I never have messed with `.git/config` before but when i compared it between the different folders the remote origin url was https not git!@ssh. It has been such a long time since i setup my original wsl instance i forgot how i set it up. I used 'Git Credential Manager". Anyways i switched the url and it fixed my issue.